# Django HttpResponseRedirect with additional query_string

Tags: python, django

I have a situation here my Signup page is served at url like this `http://localhost:8000/signUp?qid=ca1480f4` after successful signup i want to redirect the user to Login page with this query `?qid=ca1480f4`

views.py

```
class SignUp(FormView):
success_url = '/login'


def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

What changes i need to make i am getting that query with `self.request.META['QUERY_STRING']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace following line:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

with (Append the query string):

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url() + '?' + request.META['QUERY_STRING'])
```

Comment: @JorgeOrpinel, According to [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META), `request.META['QUERY_STRING']` is a unparsed query string. As long as the query string is valid, it should be okay, imho.